# Android retrieving data from webservice asynctask nullpointer

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

Here is my code:

http://pastie.org/4856109

What I want to achieve is that I want to get all the data retrieved from my inner AsyncTask to be placed on my main_activity variable named nodes...

List nodes is the variable in which i want to place all the retrieved data... any suggestion on how i could store the data retrieved to be used in the class.

if i run this code the LogCat would give me this:

> 09-28 23:00:24.978: E/Downloads(1200): java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> > 09-28 23:00:25.158: D/gralloc_goldfish(1200): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
> >
> > > 09-28 23:00:25.608: D/JSONClient(1200): "http://10.0.2.2/thesis/displayV.php"

Comment: lacks the complete stacktrace...

Comment: nodes is null. it is not initialized by the time you call it. You should be using it in onPostExecute, that's what it is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call:

```
readWebpage(null);
```

this makes an **asynchronous** call to populate your `nodes` object.  However your main thread will immediately continue to this line:

```
textView.setText((nodes.isEmpty())?"true":"false");
```

Since `nodes` is still `null` at this point (as your AsyncTask has not yet completed) then you will get the `NullPointerException` that you are experiencing.

As @njzk2 states, you should move your UI manipulation into `onPostExecute()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    textView.setText((nodes.isEmpty())?"true":"false");
}
```